# Divi Accordion Module Title HTML Tag

Tags: wordpress, divi

I am using the [Divi Accordion Module](https://www.elegantthemes.com/documentation/divi/accordion/). Divi allows me to select which heading level (1 through 6) the title of each item will be displayed as. However, I want the title of each item to be displayed as paragraph text (i.e. `p` tag) and not as a heading (i.e. `h1`, ..., `h6`). Is this possible to do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me using Divi 4.20. The additional ".no-title" class allows me to be selective in which Toggles/Accordians are affected by the change. You can add the additional class in Toggle Settings > Advanced > CSS ID & Classes > CSS Class.

```
<script>
 jQuery(function($) {
  $('.no-title .et_pb_toggle_title').each(function() {
   $(this).replaceWith("<p class='et_pb_toggle_title'>"+$(this).html()+"</p>")
  });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a default way to do that. Here is a work around using jQuery.

```
jQuery('.et_pb_toggle_title').each(function(i, obj) {
    const text = jQuery(this).text();
    jQuery(this).after('<p class="et_pb_toggle_title">'+text+'</p>');
    jQuery(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have inserted this Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.et_pb_toggle_title').each(function(i, obj) {
    const text = jQuery(this).text();
    jQuery(this).after('<p class="et_pb_toggle_title">'+text+'</p>');
    jQuery(this).remove();
});
});
</script>
```

Unfortunately, this is not a solution, only optical waste...
The headline SEO problem remains. Only basic code conversion in the DIVI Theme helps.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me (and replace heading by paragraph tag) :

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.et_pb_toggle_title').each(function(i, obj) {
      const text = jQuery(this).text();
      jQuery(this).after('<p class="et_pb_toggle_title">'+text+'</p>');
      jQuery(this).remove();
    });
  });
</script>
```